# dayjs().startOf('day') shifts two hours back

Tags: javascript, date, timezone, dayjs

I'd like to sort out a dayjs problem I am experiencing. Right now, I'm out of clues and/or guesses of what can happen, apart from the bad timezone setting. But again, how could timezone play a role here, if I didn't even modify it anywhere in my code?

I'm having a `dayjs` object, and I want to get the beginning of the day with it. When printing the output into console, I get:

```
d {
  '$L': 'en',
  '$d': 2021-03-18T22:00:00.000Z,
  '$x': {},
  '$y': 2021,
  '$M': 2,
  '$D': 19,
  '$W': 5,
  '$H': 0,
  '$m': 0,
  '$s': 0,
  '$ms': 0
}
```

Efficiently that means that month, day, week, hour, minute, second, and millisecond options are set correctly (they are all zero), but the date field in `$d` is absolutely wrong (it's shifted 2 hours back for some reason). How do I make the date update correctly as well? Please explain why does it happen so I will know how to deal with it in the future.

Using `node.js` with `express.js` to run `day.js` on.
**Node** version is 15.8.0
**Express** version is 4.17.1
**Dayjs** version is 1.10.4

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Presumably you're in UTC+2? Then the start of your day *is* 10pm the previous day in UTC.

Comment: I myself am in GMT+2. Does it return UTC start of the day by default?

Comment: No, you can see it's referring to the start of *your* day, `2021-03-19T00:00:00.000+02:00`. But in UTC, which is two hours behind, that's `2021-03-18T22:00:00.000Z `

Comment: That might be an issue if I move servers. Is there any way to make it always return `YYY-MM-DDT00:00:00.000`, as a start of a day without timezone in general, not the start of my day in particular (when converting to js date, dayjs takes exactly `$d`)?

Comment: Why are you logging the object and looking at its internal fields instead of logging the output of the `format` function?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

(Sorry for the redaction, English is not my first language)
I can answer with something that I did for my job, meanwhile some other person answer with maybe a better explanation.

In dayjs documentation there's a section for the [UTC plugin](https://day.js.org/docs/en/plugin/utc) there's a function called **.utcOffset()** which can be used to set the offset to the hours to 0, I used it because I had the same issue as you with 5 hours gap, so to obtain the date with hours in 0 I used it like this:

```
let today = dayjs().utcOffset(0).startOf('date').toDate();
```

and It gives me the date with hours, minutes and seconds in zero **2021-06-15T00:00:00.000Z**

I hope it can be of help to someone.

Answer (score -5):

The version of dayjs - 1.10.4 seems to have an issue with the startof the date. As it generally shifts the startDate by 2-5 hours.

So it's better to use moment() in place of dayjs().
I used the moment() - v2.29.1 and the issue was resolved.

instead of -
`let dateValue = dayjs(startDate)`

use

`let dateValue = moment(startDate)`

Comment: Moment is a legacy project and should not be used anymore. See: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/
Either way, recommending a different tool is not a good answer to the question.